# Views Contextual filter for matching taxonomy names

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view of content type slideshow items. Each item has a taxonomy term from`slideshow_category` vocabulary. I also have another content type: articles, which has it's own taxonomy `article_categories`.

I'd like to create a view that will match the names of those taxonomies and display the slideshow items accordingly.

**For example** on articles taxonomy page `news` the only slideshow items displayed are those which marked `news` .

**What I'm doing right now:**

I have created a contextual filter on the slideshow items view

*When is NOT available*

- Content: field_slideshow_category
- Provide Default value > Raw value from URL
- Path component > 2
- Use Path alias > checked

*When IS available*

- Specify validation criteria > checked
- Selected the `slideshow_category`
- Filter value type > Term name converted to Term ID

**PROBLEM**

This works fine on page like `/articles/news/` (using my previous example ), but obviously because I pass RAW value this view also appear on `/articles/news/news-item` (which is the actual article page). What I need is for this view to show up only on taxonomy pages. Is there a way to limit "Raw value"? should I be using a different "Provide Default value" ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes try different "Provide default value" for this case "Taxonomy term ID from URL"

When it's available specify "Taxonomy name converted to ID"

Comment: Thank you, I just tried that, but this isn't working. Now the view doesn't display items on any pages, taxonomy or not. Weird...